# How to pass multiple arguments when running Laravel Tasks on command line?

Tags: php, laravel

I created a Task class with method that needs multiple arguments:

```
class Sample_Task
{
    public function create($arg1, $arg2) {
        // something here
    }
}
```

But it seems that artisan only gets the first argument:

```
php artisan sample:create arg1 arg2
```

Error message:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for Sample_Task::create()
```

How to pass multiple arguments in this method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Sample_Task
{
    public function create($args) {
       $arg1 = $args[0];
       $arg2 = $args[1];
        // something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

*Laravel 5.2*

What you need to do is specify the argument (or option, e.g. --option) in the `$signature` property as an **array**.  Laravel indicates this with an asterisk.

**Arguments**

e.g. supposing you have an Artisan command to "process" images:

```
protected $signature = 'image:process {id*}';
```

If you then do:

```
php artisan help image:process
```

…Laravel will take care of adding the correct Unix-style syntax:

```
Usage:
  image:process <id> (<id>)...
```

To access the list, in the `handle()` method, simply use:

```
$arguments = $this->argument('id');

foreach($arguments as $arg) {
   ...
}
```

**Options**

I said it worked for options too, you use `{--id=*}` in `$signature` instead.

The help text will show:

```
Usage:
  image:process [options]

Options:
      --id[=ID]         (multiple values allowed)
  -h, --help            Display this help message

  ...
```

So the user would type:

```
php artisan image:process --id=1 --id=2 --id=3
```

And to access the data in `handle()`, you'd use:

```
$ids = $this->option('id');
```

If you omit 'id', you'll get *all* options, including booleans for 'quiet','verbose' etc.

```
$options = $this->option();
```

You may access the list of IDs in `$options['id']`

More info in the [Laravel Artisan guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan).

Comment: I think user do not need to specify --id here:

php artisan image:process --id=1 --id=2 --id=3

He can simply specify like

php artisan image:process 1 2 3

Comment: @DibyenduMitraRoy Yes. the support is better now - if it's an *argument* you can do it the way you say, if it's an *option array*, you still have to do `--id=1 --id=2` etc.  Laravel v9 docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#input-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Also could run passing the attributes:

```
php artisan image:process {id=1} {id=2} {id=3}
```