# How can my command pass through optional arguments to another Artisan command?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-dusk

### (Updated question to show that it's not like the linked questions)

I wrote a Laravel command (shown in its entirety below) that basically is a wrapper for Dusk so that I can be sure to call certain other functions beforehand. (Otherwise, I inevitably would forget to reset my testing environment.)

It works perfectly when I run `php artisan mydusk`.

```php
namespace App\Console\Commands;

class DuskCommand extends BaseCommand {

    protected $signature = 'mydusk {file?} {--filter=?}';
    protected $description = 'refreshAndSeedTestingDb, then run Dusk suite of tests';

    public function handle() {
        $this->consoleOutput($this->description);
        $resetTestingEnv = new ResetTestingEnv();
        $resetTestingEnv->refreshAndSeedTestingDb();
        $this->consoleOutput('refreshAndSeedTestingDb finished. Now will run Dusk...');
        $file = $this->argument('file');//What to do with this?
        return \Artisan::call('dusk', ['--filter' => $this->option('filter')]);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've already read [these docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#defining-input-expectations) and understand how to write the `$signature` to accept optional arguments.

My goal is to be able to sometimes run `php artisan mydusk` and also be able to optionally add arguments such as when I might want to call something like `php artisan mydusk tests/Browser/MailcheckTest.php --filter testBasicValidCaseButtonClick` (which would pass the `tests/Browser/MailcheckTest.php --filter testBasicValidCaseButtonClick` arguments through to the normal `dusk` command).

**How can I edit the last 2 lines of my `handle()` function so that `$file` gets passed to `dusk`?**

Comment: Have you read the manual? It gives examples. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#defining-input-expectations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple arguments when running Laravel Tasks on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394597/how-to-pass-multiple-arguments-when-running-laravel-tasks-on-command-line)

Comment: @fubar Yes, I'd already read those docs. I feel like maybe you didn't read my question. In any case, I've edited it now to try to make it clearer. Thanks for your help. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised to learn from my experiments that my original function actually works as I desired, and I can remove the inert line (`$file = $this->argument('file');`).

Passing the `file` argument through `\Artisan::call()` actually does not seem to be necessary at all.

@fubar's answer seems to have made the same mistaken assumptions as I originally did.

As @Jonas Staudenmeir hinted in a comment, [`Laravel\Dusk\Console\DuskCommand`](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/v3.0.9/src/Console/DuskCommand.php#L58) uses arguments from `$_SERVER['argv']`.

Comment: It works because `Laravel\Dusk\Console\DuskCommand` gets the arguments from `$_SERVER['argv']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at these links too it might help you.

[Stack Answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397082/8685260)

[Stack Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39052803/8685260)

Comment: Thanks but I'd already read those links. I feel like maybe you didn't read my question. In any case, I've edited it now to try to make it clearer. Thanks for your help. :-)

Comment: No problem i will post if i can help @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Use signature without '--' to provide arguments

```
return \Artisan::call('dusk', ['file' => $file , '--filter' => $this->option('filter')]);
```

The documentation does give an example but it is not stated clearly (it assumes you followed all the statements in the sections above)

For the signature below

```
protected $signature = 'email:send {user} {--queue}';
```

It gives (on very far below) this example as calling an Artisan command from other commands

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->call('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan#calling-commands-from-other-commands